# I am trying to creat a program to display the months and the days within the month

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

This is what i've got and im not sure how to change the nested loop to make it display each day in the IntDays array.

```
 Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click



    Dim strMonths() As String = {
                                "january", "February", "March",
                                "April", "May", "June",
                                "July", "August", "September",
                                "October", "Novemeber", "December"}
    Dim intDays() As Integer = {
                                31, 28, 31,
                                30, 31, 30,
                                31, 31, 30,
                                31, 30, 31
                            }

    For MonthCounter = 0 To strMonths.Length - 1
        ls.Items.Add(strMonths(MonthCounter) & " has " & intDays(MonthCounter).ToString & " days.")
        For DayCounter = 0 To intDays.Length - 1
            ls.Items.Add(strMonths(MonthCounter) & " " & intDays(DayCounter))

        Next

    Next




End Sub
```

Comment: You're also edging into why dates (and times) are such a pain in the backside to work with. This is only accurate on years where there's no leap year. Have a look at [this page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) to understand why it's such a mess. If you can avoid doing it yourself and use a library instead, you should always do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* like you want to display every day in the given month as a part of the inner loop.  Essentially 1-31 for January, 1-28 for February, etc ...  If so then do the following

```
Dim total = intDays(MonthCounter)
For DayCounter = 0 To total - 1
  ls.Items.Add(strMonths(MonthCounter) & " " & (DayCounter + 1))
Next
```

If this is not what you are looking for could you try revising your question with the expected output?  Not even all of it, a representative sample will be enough

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for clearing it up. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i just wanted to pop in and state that u don't have to write down all of the month like u did
u can just do the following same goes for days

```
Dim strMonths As String() = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
```